# Setting keyboard in Xamarin.Forms Entry

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

i have derived a CustomEntry from Entry.
The first letter has to be in upper case, so I use Keyboard.Chat or Keyboard.Text (with same effect)
If I "tap" into those Entries everything works fine.
But I have to set the focus programmatically to get from one to the other.
Unfortunately on iOS the Keyboards Shift-Key is not set, when I focus the entry programatically.
Funnily if I tap the backspace (on the programatically focused entry) the shift-key is set....
On Android everything is fine.

So far I've tried to set Keyboard on focus event and setting Backspace into the text. But nothing helps.

Any idea?.

Greetings Michael

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the `KeyboardFlags` when creating your `Keyboard` instead of using `Keyboard.Chat` or `Keyboard.Text`.

```
CustomEntry.Keyboard = Keyboard.Create(KeyboardFlags.CapitalizeSentence);
```

[Xamarin Source](https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/controls/choose-keyboard-for-entry/#Sentence_capitalization)

Comment: Hi,
I immediately tested this but unfornatunately without success.
Luckily the requirements changed, so that its enough to  switch to upper case in text_changed-event. But the original problem would still remain......
Greetings and thx Michael